Problemas al clonar repositorios de GitLab por SSH
Estoy experimentando problemas al clonar varios repositorios de GitLab usando SSH. Aunque algunos repositorios se clonan sin problemas, otros se quedan atascados durante el proceso. Todos estan dentro del mismo namespace Aquí hay un resumen de mi situación:
Detalles del problema:
Repositorio que no se pudo clonar:

Repositorio que se pudo clonar por htpps:

El mismo repositorio pero por ssh no se puede clonar queda travado en el proceso:

Otro repositorio del mismo name-space se puede clonar sin problema por ssh:

Autenticación: He probado la conexión SSH con el comando ssh -vT git@gitlab.com-kecharpen y la autenticación se realiza correctamente. El mensaje indica que estoy autenticado.
Intente desde distintas PC y tuve el mismo problema.
Preguntas:
¿Puede haber configuraciones en GitLab que estén causando estos problemas?
¿Alguien ha enfrentado un problema similar y podría compartir cómo lo resolvió?
¿Existen configuraciones específicas que debería revisar en los repositorios de GitLab? Agradezco cualquier ayuda o consejo que puedan ofrecer.
¡Gracias de antemano!

Tuve la misma situación en una instalación nueva de Windows 10.

La solución que encontré fue realizar el clone con https.

Después de clonar el repo, puedes hacer push o pull sin problemas.
Cabe mencionar que solo me paso en esta instalación de Windows 10, intente en otra máquina con Debian 12 y sin problemas funciono el clonado vía SSH.

El problema ocurría por una version nueva de Git for windows. El paquete todavía no esta subido para instalar por medio de winget, se debe ingresar el repositorio y bajar la nueva version de bits que corresponda.
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/discussions/5224

Pude resolver el problema que estaba experimentando al clonar varios repositorios de GitLab usando SSH. Algunos repositorios se clonaban sin problemas, mientras que otros se quedaban atascados.
Después de investigar, descubrí que el problema estaba relacionado con una actualización reciente de Git for Windows. La versión 2.47.0.windows.2 no está disponible para instalar a través de winget. Para solucionar el problema, tuve que ir directamente al repositorio de Git for Windows y descargar el instalador .exe manualmente.
Una vez que instalé la versión correcta, el proceso de clonación de todos los repositorios funcionó sin problemas.
Si alguien más está enfrentando un problema similar, les recomiendo verificar la versión de Git que están usando y considerar la actualización manual si es necesario.
¡Espero que esto ayude!
